# need to slow mass email sending in coldfusion 4.5

Tags: email, coldfusion, throttling

I'm running CF Server 4.510 on Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard SP 2.

One of our list serve applications on this server sends out a large amount of emails, prompting an excessive out-queue length alert from Barracuda.  What I'm looking to do is throttle these emails so as to not send out this alert and bog down the server.

Comment: Only queue X then run a sleep command to continue on.

Comment: @Busches not a good idea, memory will not be released if the request does not end (for CF)

Comment: @henry easily do a cflocation to the same page to keep the request from running forever

Comment: @Bushches so you need some browser to make that work?  Doesn't seem practical.  cfhttp might work though, but I'd still prefer cfschedule

Answer (score 3):

Log the email required to be sent in DB.

Use cfschedule, fetch X number of email's at a time and send them.